# Custom SQL Queries Stored in Data Table

Tags: .net, sql-server, t-sql, .net-core, ef-core-2.1

I am working on improving a health care survey for various appointment types - so there are multiple survey types, with multiple sections and questions.

Custom rules might exist like this for instance: if user answers YES to question 50 do SomethingReallyCool

=> but there is also the situation where just for customer A answering question 50 of survey 1 do SomethingDifferent

I need to some how generate dynamic, custom actions based on what clinic is conducting the survey, what survey and section it is. My question is about my idea - which is to create a SQL Server table that has SQL CODE in a `NVARCHAR(MAX)` column, run a query to see if any custom rules exist for the customer completing the survey, the section and question. Then run the string of SQL using `sp_executesql` command in SQL Server?

The process of calling this code is:

- User presses a "COMPLETE SURVEY"
- API called via AJAX
- Call stored procedure from API
- SQL Server looks for custom rules
- Executes dynamic SQL on server
- Front-end only sends the SurveyID to API. So no custom parameters are sent. SQL Injection is not a threat.

I've also thought about:

Config files that contain rules - making generic function to run the rules - keeping the rules confined to some logical boundaries?

I have thought about running some run time language like python scripts that process the rules...

I really don't want to make an API change every time we on-board a new customer.

Comment: Have you considered SurveyMonkey?

Comment: the survey application is already written is working, and in production. This is a feature that the CEO would like to offer new customers. &amp;quot;Customized Reporting&amp;quot;

Comment: You'd need to define the custom rules in detail to get a good answer. Regardless you should be able to come up with a data model that supports rules and custom 'routing' based off answer _without_ having to save custom SQL in varchar columns. For example a table that specifies a question, and which question you go to next based on the answer. That is achievable purely through a config table - no custom saved SQL or python required

Comment: It seems like the five inputs deciding on which question to go to next are: 1. Current Question, 2. Answer to Question, 3. Customer, 4. Clinic, 5. Survey (which is just the parent of question anyway, right?). The "SomethingReallyCool", "SomethingDifferent" you describe are really just more questions right? Please don't define your rules by saving strings of SQL into a database. Model the rules properly and define them in a table.